# Error on rewrite rule or any thing else

Tags: web-services, apache, mod-rewrite, passbook

I created a pass. When I add it to device, I need to register it to my server. I use .htaccess with code  :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I put this file in `https://"myIP"/passesWebserver/` and in pass.json, I add:          `"webServiceURL" : "https://"myIP"/passesWebserver/"`

I don't know I have problem with .htaccess file or what else?

Comment: now i change content of.htaccess, but still not work !       'Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me : 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/devices/(.+)/registrations/(.+)$ index.php?request=$1/devices/$2/registrations/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/passes/(.+)$ index.php?request=$1/passes/$2[L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/log$ index.php?request=$1/log [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in `.htaccess` in your passesWebserver folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ passesWebserver/index.php [L]
```

---

**Update**

To test that it is working, create a simple index.php file containing

```
<?php
$request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($request, true) . '</pre>';
```

Then when you visit `http://"myIP"/passesWebserver/v1/devices/xxx/registrations/pass.abc.def.ghi/yyy` You should see:

```
Array
(
    [0] => passesWebserver
    [1] => v1
    [2] => devices
    [3] => xxx
    [4] => registrations
    [5] => pass.abc.def.ghi
    [6] => yyy
)
```

Comment: yes ! I wrote these codes in .htaccess and put in passesWebserver already, but after adding a pass, it doesn't redirect to index.php !

Comment: Why would it redirect to index.php.  This page is only for responding to web service.  See updated answer on how to test it is working.

Comment: I use "print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);" in order to get what device sends , but it doesn't shows, so how can visit http://ip/.... ?

Comment: You still don't understand that the device that you install the pass in will automatically visit this page to register. No human will ever see this page which is why the script that you need to build has to analyse the URL, and write the Device ID to a database.  You can TEST that the script can catch any URI by visiting http://"myIP"/passesWebserver/anything/blah/foo/bar.  If your rewrite is not working you will see a `404` error.  If it is working then the code above will split up the URI and the device ID will be in $request[3].