# How a device send a POST request

Tags: web-services, post, ios6, passbook

I don't understand on how a device send a POST request to `https://webserviceURL/v1/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}`

in order to register to web server after adding a pass. How can I code in php to get data from this URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pass.json contains a valid `webserviceURL` and `authenticationToken` and it adds correctly to the device, it will just register itself - you do not have to do anything.

When you flip the pass do you see the notifications toggle?  If so, then the pass will try to register each time you toggle the notifications switch.

Things to check:

- Since you are using a MAMP set-up. Make sure that you have set up SSL correctly, and that your webServiceURL contains the correct port.  You should be able to visit `https://webserviceURL/v1/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}` and see the output in an array using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674936/error-on-rewrite-rule-or-any-thing-else/15677674#15677674).
- Make sure that Passbook logging is enable on your device (plug into Xcode, click Settings, then Developer, scroll down to PassKit Testing).
- If SSL does not work then you can enable HTTP instead for testing via the developer menu.

Then when you toggle notifications on the device you should see the registration attempt in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [How to set webServiceURL and register successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469533/how-to-set-webserviceurl-and-register-successfully)

This provides example code. If you try and have a more specific problem let us know so we can help.

Comment: I try already ! when I add a pass , I think device doesn't call webserviceURL and that's why nothing add to database.